# Логин вконтакте Standalone-приложения, OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth, android, air, actionscript, вконтакте

**Ситуация такая**: пишу Standalone-приложение на AIR for Android и решил прикрутить получение токена вконтакте. По идее эта процедура делается через внешний веб-интерфейс, но это оказалось слишком просто и я решил напрямую получить токен, притворившись браузером.

**Весь процесс делится на 4 действия**:

1. POST- или GET- запрос на получение формы логина.
2. Получение и парсинг формы логина, отправка POST-запроса с данными логина.
3. Получение формы с уведомлением, что "какое-то там приложение хочет получить доступ к
           тому-то там - согласен?".
4. Парсинг
           этой формы и отправка POST-запроса
           "согласен".

Дак вот, с первыми 3 пунктами у меня все клево, но на последний я получаю редирект на https://oauth.vk.com/error?err=2, где содержится {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Security Error"}

При этом все POST-запросы совпадают с теми, которые отправляются из браузера, когда имеешь дело с реальной формой. Я даже в блокноте оба варианта сверял - идентичные.

**Вопрос вот в чем**: Кто нибудь имел дело с вконтактовским OAuth? У кого нибудь есть какие-нибудь соображения, почему ихний сервер может возвращать такой ответ?

Comment: > При этом все POST-запросы совпадают с теми, которые отправляются из браузера, когда имеешь дело с реальной формой.

Сравните ещё заголовки.

Comment: Согласен с @falstaf. Скорее всего вы не отправляете обратно cookies, которые vk передает вам на первых шагах.

Comment: Я делал такую штуку на Python (хотел иметь возможность логиниться в API из консоли, без использования GUI): https://github.com/dzhioev/vk_api_auth. Для управления cookies использовал готовый компонент urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor. Не знаю, есть ли что-нибудь подобное в Air. A что вам мешает воспользоваться рекомедованным способом, и сделать логин через страничку открытую в WebView?

Answer (score 1):

В своем [приложении на Adobe Air](http://preferans.de/android) я сделал вход через браузер на Одноклассники, ВКонтакте, Фейсбук, Google+ и Мой мир:

[image: app screenshot]

Вот программный код для Apache Flex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
        viewActivate="loadInfo(event)"
        viewDeactivate="closeSWV(event)"
        title="Vk.com">

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource id="BACK"
            source160dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/160/back.png')"
            source240dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/240/back.png')"
            source320dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/320/back.png')"
            source480dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/480/back.png')"
            source640dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/640/back.png')" />
        <s:MultiDPIBitmapSource id="RELOAD"
            source160dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/160/reload.png')"
            source240dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/240/reload.png')"
            source320dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/320/reload.png')"
            source480dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/480/reload.png')"
            source640dpi="@Embed('assets/icons/640/reload.png')" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="portrait"/>
        <s:State name="landscape"/>
    </s:states> 

    <s:navigationContent>
        <s:Button icon="{BACK}" click="navigator.popView()"/>
    </s:navigationContent>

    <s:actionContent>
        <s:BusyIndicator id="_busy" 
                         symbolColor="0xFFFFFF" 
                         visible="false" 
                         includeInLayout="false" />
        <s:Button id="_reload" 
                  icon="{RELOAD}" 
                  click="clearInfo(event)"
                  visible="false" 
                  includeInLayout="false" />
    </s:actionContent>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.brokenfunction.json.decodeJson;
            import flash.media.StageWebView;
            import flash.net.navigateToURL;
            import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;
            import assets.avatars.male_happy;

            private static const KEY:String        = 'VK';
            private static const APP_ID:String     = '1234567';
            //private static const APP_SECRET:String = 'oXoXoXoXoXoXoXoXoXoX';
            private static const APP_URL:String    = 'http://oauth.vk.com/blank.html';
            private static const AUTH_URL:String   = 'http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?';

            private var _swv:StageWebView;

            private function openSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                _busy.visible = _busy.includeInLayout = true;
                _reload.visible = _reload.includeInLayout = false;

                _swv = new StageWebView();
                _swv.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, extractAccessToken);
                _swv.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, extractAccessToken);
                _swv.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, closeSWV);
                _swv.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, closeSWV);
                stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeSWV);

                _swv.stage = stage;
                resizeSWV();

                var reqVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
                reqVars.client_id     = APP_ID;
                reqVars.display       = 'touch';
                reqVars.response_type = 'token';
                reqVars.redirect_uri  = APP_URL;
                _swv.loadURL(AUTH_URL + reqVars);
            }

            private function closeSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                _busy.visible = _busy.includeInLayout = false;
                _reload.visible = _reload.includeInLayout = true;

                stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeSWV);
                if (! _swv)
                    return;
                _swv.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, extractAccessToken);
                _swv.removeEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE, extractAccessToken);
                _swv.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, closeSWV);
                _swv.removeEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, closeSWV);
                _swv.dispose();
                _swv = null;
            }           

            private function resizeSWV(event:Event=null):void {
                if (! _swv)
                    return;
                // align to the right-bottom corner
                _swv.viewPort = new Rectangle(stage.stageWidth - Preferans.SCALE * width, 
                    stage.stageHeight - Preferans.SCALE * height, 
                    Preferans.SCALE * width, 
                    Preferans.SCALE * height);
            }

            private function extractAccessToken(event:Event):void {
                trace('title: ' + _swv.title);
                trace('location: ' + _swv.location);

                var access_token:String = getValue('access_token=', _swv.location);
                var user_id:String = getValue('user_id=', _swv.location);
                if (access_token && user_id) {
                    trace('access_token=' + access_token);
                    trace('user_id=' + user_id);

                    closeSWV();

                    fetchInfo(access_token, user_id);
                }
            }

            private function fetchInfo(access_token:String, userid:String):void {
                var reqVars:Array = new Array();
                reqVars.push('user_ids=' + userid);
                //reqVars.push('access_token=' + access_token);
                reqVars.push('fields=city,photo_big,sex');
                reqVars.push('v=5.10');

                var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
                req.url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?' + reqVars.join('&');

                var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete); 
                loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, handleError);
                loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleError);

                try {
                    loader.load(req);
                    _busy.visible = _busy.includeInLayout = true;
                    _reload.visible = _reload.includeInLayout = false;
                } catch (error:Error) {
                    trace(error);
                }
            }

            private function handleError(event:ErrorEvent):void {
                _busy.visible = _busy.includeInLayout = false;
                _reload.visible = _reload.includeInLayout = true;

                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target); 
                trace(event.text);
                trace(loader.data);
            }

            private function handleComplete(event:Event):void {
                _busy.visible   = _busy.includeInLayout   = false;
                _reload.visible = _reload.includeInLayout = true;

                var obj:Object;
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target); 
                trace(loader.data);
                try {
                    obj = decodeJson(loader.data, true)['response'][0];
                    saveInfo(obj);
                    loadInfo(null, false);
                } catch (e:Error) {
                    trace('Invalid JSON: ' + loader.data);
                }
            }

            private function clearInfo(obj:Object):void {
                data = null;

                delete (Preferans.SO.data)[KEY];
                Preferans.SO.flush();

                loadInfo();
            }

            private function saveInfo(obj:Object):void {
                data = { 
                    ID:     KEY + obj.id,
                    AUTH:   Preferans.GENERATE_HASH(obj.id),
                    FIRST:  obj.first_name,
                    LAST:   obj.last_name,
                    FEMALE: (obj.sex != 2),
                    AVATAR: obj.photo_big
                };

                try {
                    data.CITY = obj.city.title;
                } catch (e:Error) {
                    // ignore eventual null pointer
                }

                (Preferans.SO.data)[KEY] = data;
                Preferans.SO.flush();

                Preferans.ID    = data.ID;
                Preferans.AUTH  = data.AUTH;
                Preferans.FIRST = data.FIRST;
            }

            private function loadInfo(event:ViewNavigatorEvent=null, displaySWV:Boolean=true):void {
                localize();

                data = (Preferans.SO.data)[KEY];
                if (Preferans.CHECK_INFO(data)) {
                    _first.text = resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.first') + ' ' + data.FIRST;
                    _gender.text = resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.gender') + ' ' + 
                        (data.FEMALE ? resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.female') : 
                            resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.male'));
                    _city.text = resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.city') + ' ' + (data.CITY ? data.CITY : '');

                    // will be displayed in Avatar.mxml, do not scale down
                    data.zoom = Preferans.avatarRequest(
                        data.AVATAR as String, 
                        data.FEMALE as Boolean
                    );

                    _avatar.source = Preferans.avatarRequest(
                        data.AVATAR as String, 
                        data.FEMALE as Boolean,
                        Preferans.AVATAR_WIDTH,
                        Preferans.AVATAR_HEIGHT
                    );

                    _busy.visible   = _busy.includeInLayout   = false;
                    _reload.visible = _reload.includeInLayout = true;
                    _play.visible   = _play.includeInLayout   = true;
                } else {
                    _play.visible   = _play.includeInLayout   = false;

                    if (displaySWV)
                        openSWV();
                }
            }

            private function getValue(key:String, str:String):String {
                const pattern:RegExp = /[-_a-zA-Z0-9\/.]+/;
                var index:int = str.indexOf(key);
                if (index > -1) {
                    var matches:Array = str.substring(index + key.length).match(pattern);
                    if (matches.length > 0)
                        return matches[0];
                }
                return null;
            }

            private function showProfile(event:MouseEvent):void {
                navigateToURL(new URLRequest('http://preferans.de/' + data.ID));
            }

            private function startGame(event:MouseEvent):void {
                var ngames:int = int(Preferans.SO.data.NGAMES);
                ngames = (isNaN(ngames) ? 1 : ngames + 1);
                Preferans.SO.data.NGAMES = ngames;
                Preferans.SO.data.LAST_KEY = KEY;
                Preferans.SO.flush();

                navigator.pushView(Main, data);
            }

            private function zoomAvatar(event:MouseEvent):void {
                navigator.pushView(Avatar, data);
            }

            private function localize():void {
                _desc.text = resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.desc');
                _first.text = resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.first');
                _gender.text = resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.gender');
                _city.text = resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.city');
                _play.label = resourceManager.getString('resources', 'login.play');
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout.portrait>
        <s:VerticalLayout horizontalAlign="center"
                          paddingLeft="{Preferans.PADDING}"
                          paddingTop="{Preferans.PADDING}"
                          gap="{Preferans.PADDING}" />
    </s:layout.portrait>
    <s:layout.landscape>
        <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle" 
                            paddingLeft="{Preferans.PADDING}"
                            paddingTop="{Preferans.PADDING}"
                            gap="{Preferans.PADDING}" />
    </s:layout.landscape>

    <s:Group click="zoomAvatar(event)">
        <s:BitmapImage id="_avatar" 
                       width="{Preferans.AVATAR_WIDTH}" 
                       height="{Preferans.AVATAR_HEIGHT}" 
                       scaleMode="letterbox"
                       source="{male_happy}"
                       contentLoader="{Preferans.AVATAR_CACHE}" />
    </s:Group>

    <s:VGroup paddingTop="{Preferans.PADDING}"
              paddingLeft="{Preferans.PADDING}"
              paddingRight="{Preferans.PADDING}"
              paddingBottom="{Preferans.PADDING}">
        <s:VGroup>
            <s:Label id="_desc" />
            <s:Label id="_first"  />
            <s:Label id="_gender" />
            <s:Label id="_city"   />
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:VGroup>

    <s:Button id="_play"
              click="startGame(event)"
              includeInLayout="false"
              visible="false" />
</s:View>
```